# Mongoose get value from embedded document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database, nosql

[image]i have a scheme like this

```
 var WFWorkItemDocument = new Schema({
        id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, default: uuid.v1 },
        description: { type: String },
        period: [{
            id: { type: String, default: uuid.v1 },
            start: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
            due: { type: Number, integer: true },
            new: { type: Number, integer: true },
        }],
```

i want to get the period's due value for that i used a method like

```
    WorkItem.findOne({ id: idUpdate }, function(err, WorkItem) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("invlaid id");
                //return res.send(404, { error: 'invalid id' });
            }

            if (WorkItem) {
                console.log("id");
                console.log(WorkItem.period.due);

            } else {
                //res.send(404, new Error('Workitem not found'));
            }
});
```

but it doesn't work how can i get the due value??

This is the result for console.log(WorkItem)

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  What is your console logging?  Maybe this is because there are two 'due' fields of different types?

Comment: sorry there is only one due i have edited it. it says due not defined. i used console logging just to see the output on console log

Comment: Can you try changing the name of the work item in the callback function?  Maybe the WorkItem is referencing the Schema instead of the Document it found.  

For instance: function(err, item) , if (item), and then console.log(item.period.due).

Please let me know what console.log messages are occurring!

Comment: You define `period` as an array of embedded

Comment: @dyouberg ya i tried like that but still it gives undefined

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani maybe is there a way to get the due data from that array

Comment: Can you log just WorkItem instead of WorkItem.period.due and post the result in your question please?

Comment: @dyouberg i have added the console.log result of Workitem

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani is correct.  You are returning an array and trying to access a value directly.  

You'll see the answer if you try logging console.log(WorkItem.period[0].due)

You're best off changing the schema so you aren't using an array if you don't need it.

Comment: Yes now it works thank you @dyouberg

Answer (score 2):

Change the schema to embed one object. Unless you need embedded array.

```
 var WFWorkItemDocument = new Schema({
        id: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, default: uuid.v1 },
        description: { type: String },
        period: {
            id: { type: String, default: uuid.v1 },
            start: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
            due: { type: Number, integer: true },
            new: { type: Number, integer: true },
        },
```

And if you define it as an embedded array, you can access like :

`WorkItem.period[index].due`

Comment: i tried WorkItem.period[index].due but it still gives undefined error.

Comment: @kohli Which version of monsoose do you use? And `index` means you enter an index number like `0`, `1`. And if you change your schema according my answer, you need to insert new data based on new schema

Comment: Sorry i'm getting the correct value now. i used WorkItem.period[0].due for it. Thank you @Ebrahim Pasbani

Comment: You're getting the correct value but you had to do it this way because your schema is wrong.  It's better practice to fix your schema than to do a workaround every time.

Comment: @kohli , dyouberg is right. Your data model needs to be fixed. Every work item embeds only one period

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani i got the point thank you for explaining about the best practice as well

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani if i do the schema as you mentioned above i can get the value by giving Workitem.period.due is it??

Comment: @kohli yes, you can